# How does Max Pooling handle Odd Image Dimensions?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, pooling

For the even image dimension case, max pooling is simple to understand - it simply performs convolution over the image with the max operator with a $x$-by-$x$ kernel with a stride of $x$. However for the case of images with odd image dimensions, you have to make a design choice: do you zero-pad the image then max pool or do you simply crop out the last column/row? How is this handled by standard max pooling layers in, say, Theano and Tensorflow? I'm wondering because when I use Theano, the image dimensions are reduced by integer division (which uses a floor function), which suggests that the second method is used, since if you were to zero-pad this would result in "ceiling division" (division followed by the ceiling function instead of the floor function).

Comment: This link seems to explain how Tensorflow handles the situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t

Comment: Keras/Tensorflow seems to be cropping the last columns by default.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer entirely depends on software implementations -- there's no mathematical or statistical content.

Comment: @Sycorax I agree, it didn't really fit into CV, thank you for closing.